# Why is the length usually calculated this way for BubbleSort algorithm?

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

So I'm just trying to understand how bubblesort (it may help me with other algorithms when I see this kind of stuff as well) works with the nested for loop.

I noticed that most people will do the loops like so:

```cs
public static void BubbleSort(int[] arr, int arr_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    bool swapped;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (j = 0; j < arr_size - i -1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }            
}
```

I have done it like this (only slightly different; note the nested loop size check:

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] arr, int arr_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    bool swapped;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (j = 0; j < arr_size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }            
}
```

And it seems to work with every check I've done so far.

I guess to sum it up, I am wondering why the first loop would be the size - 1 (I know this is because of the whitespace at the end) and the nested loop will be the size - i - 1 (at least I have seen this a lot). Thanks for any feedback !

Comment: Your loop is the super set of the correct code. Sure, it will work but it will run in N^2 time instead of N log(N) time. Because you check more items

Comment: @Emad It's not O(N log(N)), it's just O(N^2/2) which is still O(N^2).  It just happens to cut out about half the steps.

Comment: To expand on @Emad's answer: Once an item has been sorted into place, it isn't going to move again -- and thus there is no need to check it.  Your loop checks and rechecks already sorted items.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort
Checkout what the worst case differs from usual cases. Worst case is not always happening. In your code it always does.

Comment: Ahh okay, I think I understand now! I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of the inner loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < arr_size - i - 1; j++)
{
    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
    {
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
    }
}
```

is finding the maximum element in the array and placing it to the last position. Hence, for `i == 0` (the index from the outer loop), it moves it to the last array position. For `i == 1`, the array's overall maximum element is already at the last array position, and hence it does not need to be processed again. For `i == 2` etc. the situation is the same. In other words, the array is being sorted from 'backward' by 'bubbling' (hence the algorithm's name) the maximum elements up each iteration.

There is a nice step-by-step example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

In your second example, by omitting the `- i` in the `for` loop clause, you are just unnecessarily checking array elements that are already in place from previous (outer loop) iterations and hence cannot change anymore.

Comment: This answer is just what I've been looking for. I appreciate your time for this very much!